# Entity Framework Core exception: No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'JsonDocument'

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, unit-testing, in-memory-database

I got this error while running **unit tests**. There's no error when locally testing the app. The simplified class using JsonDocument is:

```
[Table("configuration")]
public class Configuration: IDisposable
{
    [Column("value", TypeName = "json")]
    [Required]
    public JsonDocument Value { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.Schema.Dispose();
            this.Value.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'JsonDocument'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'utf8Json', 'parsedData', 'extraRentedArrayPoolBytes', 'extraPooledByteBufferWriter', 'isDisposable' in 'JsonDocument(ReadOnlyMemory<byte> utf8Json, MetadataDb parsedData, byte[] extraRentedArrayPoolBytes, PooledByteBufferWriter extraPooledByteBufferWriter, bool isDisposable)'.
```

I've search for this error and found this Github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2902

I tried it, and it works. **Is there any other option?** I don't like the idea of extending my DbContext class because this problem is interfering with around 500 unit tests, and a lot of files using the DbContext directly. Is there an elegant solution for this?
The solution I implemented in my unit tests db context class is the same as the github solution:

```
public class UnitTestMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    public UnitTestMyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Configuration>().Property(p => p.Value)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToJson(),
                v => v.FromJson<JsonDocument>());
    }
}
```

I also used this page as reference:
https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#jsondocument-dom-mapping

- Is there any better way to do this?
- Is there another way to read a json data type in postgres without mapping it to string or POCO?
- Is there a way to not touch much the unit tests InMemoryDatabase configuration for them to correctly read the JsonDocument type?

Comment: This isn't an NpgSQL issue. Its EF Core provider can already handle JsonDocument. It's the in-memory provider that fails EF Core doesn't support JSON columns yet. [This is planned for EF Core 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/plan#json-columns). The NpgSQL uses its own built-in JSON provider to persist JsonDocument to jsonb.

Comment: One option would be to modify the in-memory provider to support JsonDocument. [The InMemoryTypeMappingSource](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/0d1d602d72fefe14f12a86410ec70394ec8151e0/src/EFCore.InMemory/Storage/Internal/InMemoryTypeMappingSource.cs#L43) class creates mappings for all value types, strings, bytes and geometry types by simply creating a mapping class with a comparer. Perhaps all that's needed is to add 3-4 lines to create a mapping for JsonDocument as well

Answer (score 1):

From the link in your question

"Note that neither a data annotation nor the fluent API are required, as JsonDocument is automatically recognized and mapped to jsonb."

JsonDocument class doesn't have any properties, so if you want to use JsonDocument as a common Net class, you will have at first create Net class with the properties are needed. Only after this  you can add NotMapped property of created class and put all logic in getters/setters.

IMHO Value is not the best name of a class property, since it is very commonly use in Net framework as a property value, not as a name.So it can cause some confussions. It is better to change it.

Comment: About the Value property name, sure, but that's only for the sample code provided. The class name is also simplified.
About the rest of it, thank you! I'll check that out too.